# Matar un proceso/hilo al cabo de cierto tiempo si no ha terminado

Tags: c#, servicio, asynctask

Actualmente tenemos un servicio que lee diferentes TAGs de WINCC e inserta esos valores a una base de datos Se trata de un proceso donde se leen miles de tags.

Normalmente el servicio funciona bien, pero a veces, no sabemos el motivo, se queda pillado leyendo algún TAG (este hecho es aleatorio y no hemos podido identificar el motivo) y hay que reiniciarlo.

Para Solucionarlo la solución que se me ha ocurrido es que que la lectura y escritura de dichos tags se hagan en un hilo aparte y que si, pasado cierto tiempo, ese hilo no responde o no ha terminado el trabajo se pueda matar para volver a lanzarlo mas adelante.

He probado utilizando IAsyncResult de la siguiente manera:

```
        StatisticalData data = enviosCompletados;
        IAsyncResult ar = data.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        DateTime fin = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second).AddMinutes(1);
        while (!ar.IsCompleted && (DateTime.Now < fin))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Posicion " + porcentajecompletado);                
        }           

        if (!ar.IsCompleted || !envioCorrecto) 
        {                   
            Debug.WriteLine("Final " + porcentajecompletado,    data.EndInvoke(ar).ToString() + " ...Segundos");                            
            // borrar Tablas
        }
        else
        {

            //  proceso completado correctamente
        }
```

para simular que se atasca el proceso he puesto:

```
    while (1==1){}
```

en enviosCompletados.

Sin embargo he comprobado que después del

```
data.EndInvoke(ar)...
```

el while sigue vivo.

Me gustaría saber como hacer para matar el proceso "data" o si existe alguna alternativa mejor, quizás usando tasks o background... etc.

**La clave en este servicio seria controlar si ha terminado o no un proceso en un determinado tiempo y en caso de no haber terminado poder matarlo**

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tan simple como poner el proceso dentro de la condición:

```
if (!process.WaitForExit(1800))
{
    // aquí el proceso que quieres terminar
}
```

debes poner el nombre de tu proceso, el `WaitForExit` lo que hace es esperar a que el proceso termine, si le especificas un tiempo (en ms) matará el proceso después de el tiempo transcurrido, espero que te sirva, si no es así hazmelo saber.